# If $B_1, B_2 \subseteq Y$ and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ then $f^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_2)=f^{-1}(B_1) \cap f^{-1}(B_2)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

From the textbook "Classic Set Theory" by D. Goldrei I tried the following

**Problem:** If $A_1, A_2 \subseteq X$, $B_1, B_2 \subseteq Y$ and $f: X \rightarrow Y$, decide if $f^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_2)=f^{-1}(B_1) \cap f^{-1}(B_2)$.

Note, that here $f^{-1}(B_1) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \in B_1\}$, that is the set of pre-images of all $y \in B_1$.

I came up with the following

**Proof:** Assume that $x\in f^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_2)$, then $x$ has a unique image $f(x)\in B_1 \cap B_2$. Thus we can conclude that any pre-image (there might be more than one) of this $f(x)$ is an element of $f^{-1}(B_1)$ and $f^{-1}(B_2)$ and so we have $x \in f^{-1}(B_1) \cap f^{-1}(B_2)$.

For the converse let us assume that $x \in f^{-1}(B_1) \cap f^{-1}(B_2)$. So $x \in f^{-1}(B_1)$ and $x \in f^{-1}(B_2)$ and thus $f(x) \in B_1$ as well as $f(x) \in B_2$. Since $f^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_2)$ contains the pre-images of all elements of $B_1 \cap B_2$, we have $x \in f^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_2)$ as required. $\blacksquare$

I post this here, since those conclusions about images and pre-images are not that simple for me. For the different problem to decide if $f(A_1 \cap A_2)=f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$ I found a counter-example. But I couldn't find one here.

So, is my proof correct? Thanks in advance for any comment and correction.

Comment: Your proof is quite correct. You should alike try to check what happens if you change both $\cap$ to $\cup$ in your formula; and also what can be said about $f^{-1}(Y\smallsetminus B)$ (preimage of any $B\subset Y$).

Comment: @jp boucheron thanks for the comment; just did this since it was another part of the excercise; am I right, that equality holds in both cases?

Comment: Yes. _Inverse_ images of sets behave nicely. On the other hand, with _direct images_ you only have $f(B_1\cap B_2) \subset f(B_1)\cap f(B_2)$ in general (but equality holds if $f$ is injective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct! As a little comment you could maybe restructure the first part of your proof a bit to something like:

> Let $x' \in X$ be such that $f(x') = f(x)$, then $f(x') \in B_1 \cap
> B_2$, and so $x' \in f^{-1}(B_1) \cap f^{-1}(B_2)$.

This is a bit more clear and explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine, but here's a more efficient way to say the same thing.  For any $x\in X$, each of the following statements is equivalent, by definition of $f^{-1}$ or of $\cap$, to the next.

$x\in f^{-1}(B_1\cap B_2)$

$f(x)\in B_1\cap B_2$

$f(x)\in B_1$ and $f(x)\in B_2$

$x\in f^{-1}(B_1)$ and $x\in f^{-1}(B_2)$

$x\in f^{-1}(B_1)\cap f^{-1}(B_2)$.

So the sets $f^{-1}(B_1\cap B_2)$ and $f^{-1}(B_1)\cap f^{-1}(B_2)$ contain exactly the same members $x$ and are therefore equal.

Comment: Note that  you get a proof of the analogous result for $\cup$ (or for $\setminus$) by just changing every $\cap$ to $\cup$ (or to $\setminus$) and every "and" to  "or" (or to "but not").